# 4-20 mA analogue signal conversion to flow rate

Tags: control-system, conversion, 4-20ma

I have the following control setup:
[image]

For that, I have data recorded for every I/O block, and I am asked to determine the function used by the AIN block to convert from an analogue 4-20 mA signal to a flow value in the range of 0/32 L/m. The plotted data looks like this:
[image]
How would you obtain that function?
Thanks for your time

Comment: This is called „curve fitting“. You can do that e.g. with Excel.

Comment: The [R project](https://www.r-project.org) also has functions for curve-regression-fitting.

Comment: There could be an offset issue though, why zero flow doesn't give 4mA? Then do you know the expected law of dP to flow conversion? It's a well known one.This is indeed needed to know which function fit to your curve